# Performance issue in ThreeJS while using InterLeavedBuffer

Tags: three.js

I used InterleaveleavedBuffer to manage the data and render the mesh in the browsers. I have a instances of 16000 objects from one object and when I check the draw call its 1, but while I try to Pan, rotate , zoom in/out the browser gets crashes and the response of the functionalities are very slow. I have no idea about it but as I know it has a minimal number of draw calls although why it should crash the browser.

Is there any idea to over come it and improve the performance of the viewer.

My brwoser: Version 80.0.3987.149 (Official Build) (64-bit)

[image]

Comment: What amount of memory on your GPU? Just out of curiousity.

Comment: haha @prisoner849 NVIDIA GeForce GT 710